# How to get X & Y rows to match?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm working on a new type of code and need a little help with the ridge regularized regression.  trying to build a predictive model but first i need x and y matrix rows to match.

I found something similar with a google search but their data is randomly generated and not provided like mine is.  the data is a large dataset with over 500,000 observations and 670 variables.

```
 library(rsample)
 library(glmnet)
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)

 # Create training (70%) and test (30%) sets
 # Use set.seed for reproducibility

 set.seed(123)

 alumni_split<-initial_split(alumni, prop=.7, strata = "Id.Number")
 alumni_train<-training(alumni_split)
 alumni_test<-testing(alumni_split)

 #----
 # Create training and testing feature model matrices and response 
 vectors.
 # we use model.matrix(...)[, -1] to discard the intercept
 alumni_train_x <- model.matrix(Id.Number ~ ., alumni_train)[, -1]
 alumni_test_x <- model.matrix(Id.Number ~ ., alumni_test)[, -1]

 alumni_train_y <- log(alumni_train$Id.Number)
 alumni_test_y <- log(alumni_test$Id.Number)

 # What is the dimension of of your feature matrix?
 dim(alumni_train_x)

 #---- [HERE]
 # Apply Ridge regression to alumni data
   alumni_ridge <- glmnet(alumni_train_x, alumni_train_y, alpha = 0)
```

The error message (with code):

alumni_ridge <- glmnet(alumni_train_x, alumni_train_y, alpha = 0)
     Error in glmnet(alumni_train_x, alumni_train_y, alpha = 0) : 
      number of observations in y (329870) not equal to the number of rows of 
      x (294648)

Comment: Hey @vike238, welcome to SO. It would be nice for this question and future ones you provide some data (even random). I tried to use the mtcars dataset, for example, and there was no error message.

Comment: Ooops! thank for the tip and I'll try the same thing (using random data) if I still get an error message I'll reply back.